# onActivityResult from one fragment to other

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my `recyclerview` `adapter`, I have defined the onClick as:

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          Snackbar.make(view, "View Clicked: "+Double.toString(position)+", "+current.getPlace(),
                  Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
      });
```

This view contains `latitude` and `longtidue` of a place. Now, my goal is to transfer the LatLng to OnActivityResult which is on MapFragment to show the map.

In my map fragment, I already have an onActivityResult as:

```
 int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    try {
      startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    } catch(GooglePlayServicesRepairableException |
        GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
  }

  // Get LatLng from placePicker
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, getContext());
        String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
        System.out.println(place);
        Snackbar.make(getView(), toastMsg, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        latlang.Lat = place.getLatLng().latitude;
        latlang.Lang = place.getLatLng().longitude;
        addMarker(place); 
 ....
}
```

Since I am new in java, I can't solve how to get the data from the adapter to this `onActivityResult`.

pseudocode will be really helpful.

Comment: does adapter is in MapFragment? or its in different fragment?

Comment: adapter is in another fragment

Comment: @HemantParmar: As I said, due to my inexperience in java, I cant solve this. I have checked the link you suggested before, but unfortunately, that is not enough for me

Comment: give some more code.. usually we do not use onactivityresult method for communication between fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I implement like this, via send broadcast

1, send broadcast from where you have latitude, longitude like below.

```
   Intent intente = new Intent("visible_text");
   intente.putExtra("lati", coordl1);
   intente.putExtra("longi", coordl2);
   intente.putExtra("name", strAddress);
   intente.putExtra("from", "drop");
   sendBroadcast(intente);
   finish();
```

2, now you can get in your fragment/adepter whatever you want 
   #Register broadcast in on resume as below,

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
registerReceiver(broadcast_reciever_visible_text,newIntentFilter("visible_text"));
}
```

3, now unregister receiver in ondestroy method like below

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcast_reciever_visible_text);
}
```

4, now you get latitude or longitude from receiver it may global like below

```
  BroadcastReceiver broadcast_reciever_visible_text = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals("visible_text")) {
            if (MyUtills.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
                lati = intent.getExtras().getString("lati");
                longi = intent.getExtras().getString("longi");
                location_name = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
                TAG_FROM = intent.getExtras().getString("from");

               }
          }
    }
};
```

now I hope you implement this and working Happy coding...